# Possible to assign extra "data" to a chart point in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I know I can retrieve this.x and this.y from a data point, but is it possible to have set things up in such a way that I can also get this.myVar?

I've put it in the data array that I pass in:

```
[
    {x: 953337600000, y: 17, myVar: 1217},
    {x: 955152000000, y: 9,  myVar: 1305}
]
```

Etc, and that renders as expected, the same as if myVar wasn't there.

But I can't access this.myVar later in the JS.

I tried accessing this.point.myVar and am told that this.point is undefined?

Is there something trivial I can do to achieve this goal?

Thanks

Comment: You can access it under `point.options`, so for example `point.options.myVar`.

Comment: "point is not defined". I'm trying to access it in the tooltip formatter function, if that helps...

Comment: Is the tooltip shared? If not it should then be `this.point.options.myVar`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "shared", but I don't think so.  this.point is undefined, sadly.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/b3sanahh/

Comment: Ah, no!  I tell a lie, it WAS a shared tooltip.  My bad, sorry.  Thank you for your help kind stranger!